# What is set operation is doing?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

From the following example, I'm clearly doing something wrong.

I'm trying to update `node2.data` (in a new tree) to be equal to `9`. But the result is `node1.data===9` (in a new tree) and the content of `node1.next` is missing.

Why?

```js
const node2 = {data: 2, next: []};
const node1 = {data: 1, next: [node2]};

const head1 = Immutable.fromJS(node1);
const head2 = head1.get('next').get(0).set('data', 9);
console.log(head2.get('data')); // 9
console.log(head2.get('next').get(0)); // undefined
// expected output: 1 and {.... object ...}!==undefined
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/4.0.0-rc.12/immutable.js"></script>
```

Comment: `set` is working as expected, it returns a new object with the `data` value updated to `9`. But you are never doing anything about `head1`, you only access values inside it but don't construct a new updated `head1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [setIn](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/setIn):

`const head2 = Immutable.setIn(head1, ['next', 0, 'data'], 9)`